# Why is ref not a property in children components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've recently noticed that in ReactJS passing `ref` to a component as property is not possible.

Here's my Code:

```
class A extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <B
            ref={ref=>this.bRef = ref} 
        />
    }
}

class B extends React.Component{
    render(){
        console.log(this.props.ref) //=>undefined
        return <div
            {...this.props}
        />
    }
}
```

`this.bRef` will be undefined in `A`. Is there a explanation about this?

Comment: thats not how ref works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a explanation about this?

The issue you are seeing is due to the fact that `key` and `ref` are special props.
[See](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)

> Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however,
>   there are two special props (ref and key) which are used by React, and
>   are thus not forwarded to the component.
>
> For instance, attempting to access this.props.key from a component
>   (i.e., the render function or propTypes) is not defined. If you need
>   to access the same value within the child component, you should pass
>   it as a different prop (ex: `<ListItemWrapper key={result.id}
>   id={result.id} />`). While this may seem redundant, it’s important to
>   separate app logic from reconciling hints.

To access ref in child pass it in a different prop. 
Say you create a `ref` like

```
const ref = React.createRef();
```

and then you pass it to your component as shown below:

```
<FancyButton forwardedRef={ref} text="Click ME!" />
```

where inside the `FancyButton` the ref will be available as

```
 <button
      onClick={() => {
        this.logRef(forwardedRef);
      }}
      ref={forwardedRef}
    >
      {text}
 </button>
```

where `logRef` is defined as

```
logRef(myref) {
    console.log(myref.current);
}
```

a working example can be seen at (Click on the button and check the console) : https://codesandbox.io/s/ko6wnrorv

Comment: Thanks. Didn't found the Special Props Warning site from React.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

ref does not behave like a regular props. It has a special meaning.

```
class A extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <B
            ref={ref=>this.bRef = ref} 
        />
    }
}
```

what it means here is, you are getting a reference of component 'B' in component 'A'. That is, you can use this.bRef to call some methods in component 'B' from component 'A'

*Note: this.bRef will get it's value only after A and B is rendered until then it will be undefined.*