# React - changing key prop doesn't cause rerender of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-props

I am using [react-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller) to render a feed of data. Whenever the user changes their settings, I want to refresh the feed of data.

To do this, I have a key prop for the `InfiniteScroll` component. The idea being whenever the user changes their settings

1. `this.state.renderCount` is incremented by 1 in `setState`
2. React notices that the key prop of `InfiniteScroll` is different, and re-renders the component from scratch.

   ```
     <Content style={{ padding: "0px 20px" }}>
       <InfiniteScroll
         key={this.state.renderCount}
         style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
         pageStart={0}
         loadMore={this.loadPosts.bind(this)}
         hasMore={true}
         loader={<div>Loading....</div>}
         useWindow={false}
       >
         {listItems}
       </InfiniteScroll>
     </Content>
   ```

The refresh code is in `componentDidUpdate` and is called if I determine that a refresh is needed:

```
  this.setState({ renderCount: this.state.renderCount + 1 })
```

However, the component is not reset. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but React has a special purpose for the `key` prop, to make sure that siblings can be uniquely identified. That may be why your component is not refreshing. I would try to use a different property name and see if that works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overthinking it.

With the way react-infinite-scroll works, I just have to clear the `listItems` array.

In my case, I just had to do:

```
  this.setState({ templates: [] })
```

(`listItems` is generated by a map function that maps templates to jsx).

Answer (score 2):

`key` and `ref` are special keywords in react. [See](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)

> Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however,
>   there are two special props (ref and key) which are used by React, and
>   are thus not forwarded to the component.
>
> For instance, attempting to access this.props.key from a component
>   (i.e., the render function or propTypes) is not defined. If you need
>   to access the same value within the child component, you should pass
>   it as a different prop (ex: `<ListItemWrapper key={result.id}
>   id={result.id} />`). While this may seem redundant, it’s important to
>   separate app logic from reconciling hints.

To pass they `key` prop to the child element use another name.

See also : [Why is ref not a property in children components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668781/why-is-ref-not-a-property-in-children-components/53669801#53669801)